# How to return all the id's with common value for another field in cosmos sql api?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

the cosmos doc is in this structure

```json
{
orderNumber: 1,
productNumber:p1
},
{
orderNumber: 1,
productNumber:p2
},
{
orderNumber: 2,
productNumber:p3
}
```

how do I return the list of productsnumber within the same ordernumber.
for example, the result should be like

```json
{
orderNumber:1,
products:{
p1,
p2
}
```

select c.orderNumber,count(c.orderNumber)
from c
group by c.orderNumber

I tried this query to get the count on ordernumber, which gives the product count, but how can we return the actual productNumber.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you’ve tried, output issues, etc. also - have you looked into GROUP BY? That will likely help you.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thanks for your response, I was able to count the products number in an order using group by, but not able to figure out how to return the product id's for an order.